# Getting absolute path to the file inside the public folder in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file

What is the best way to get absolute path to the file inside the public folder in controller? Is there a predefined Rails variable that holds absolute path to the public folder?

Currently I'm using `File.expand_path('../../../public', __FILE__)`, but I'm sure there's a nicer way of doing this.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`Rails.public_path` should provide you the public path

Comment: Great, thanks! I also found  "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public", but your method is way nicer.

Comment: Thanks William and Vincent... it's much usefull for me

Comment: is there any other way to do it? it doesn't work for me (I need to paste the path for the file in my model)

Comment: Glad to see that you got an answer that works for you (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714645/path-to-public-folder-from-a-model).