# How to specify the path of the public directory in a ruby on rails app?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to parse .csv file which is in `public` folder, I've tried `/../`'s, `#{RAILS_ROOT}/public` but with no success (No such file or directory error). I dunno exactly how to use `Rails.public_path` (`Rails.public_path/filename.csv` doesn't work) please help

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have access to the `Rails.root` path, use it to get a path

```
Rails.root.join("public", "filename.csv")
```

You'll possibly have to call `to_s` on it depending on how you want to use the result (as a `Path` object or as a string).

Answer (score 19):

In Rails 4, `Rails.public_path`, like `Rails.root`, returns a stdlib [Pathname object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html), so you can also use `join` with it:

```
 Rails.public_path.join('filename.csv')
```

Comment: This only works in rails 4 or later; in rails 3, `Rails.public_path` is a string

Comment: @robd thanks for the heads up. I've clarified that in the answer. Keeping it here even though it was tagged Rails 3 for future readers.