# Rails 5.1 : url helper for files in public folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, actionview

In Rails 5.1, there is a deprecation warning if we use asset_path for files in public folder.

`DEPRECATION WARNING: The asset "favicon.ico" is not present in the asset pipeline.Falling back to an asset that may be in the public folder.
This behavior is deprecated and will be removed.`

So I tried `public_asset_path`, but it is not working, is there a helper?

Comment: I got the same error when I am referencing an external resource, i.e: an image on aws or anywhere else

Comment: Any solution you found yet?

Comment: no , still waiting

Comment: Well, I found mine, the issue was with the URL, URL was being appended with another https: while it already had http:// so complete URL was like https:http://xyz.abc which is obviously not right. Fixing the URL generator in my app fixed the problem. On a few places, I had the completely wrong path to file, i.e path was not even path, also fixed that thanks to this warning. :)

Comment: @NicolasMaloeuvre did you found a solution?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

So I added this method in helpers/application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def public_path(path)
      "#{ Rails.env.development? ? 'http://localhost:3000/' : 'https://cdn.mysite.fr/' }#{ path }"
  end
end
```

and then I can use `public_path('images/image.jpg')` in views

Answer (score 22):

If want to use helper method without asset pipeline, need to specify the `skip_pipeline` option.

Like this.

`image_path("user/favicon.png", skip_pipeline: true)`

Or if want to enable asset fallback for the entire application,
`config.assets.unknown_asset_fallback` can be set to true.
See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#raise-an-error-when-an-asset-is-not-found

Comment: In case someone may need alternative full-form asset_path version: `ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('favicon.ico', host: "https://example.com", skip_pipeline: true)`

Answer (score -1):

you can use `Rails.public_path` to get the public directory and then find the file from there, you could also use `#{RAILS_ROOT}/public` they would both do the same thing.

Source: [Getting absolute path to the file inside the public folder in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323471/getting-absolute-path-to-the-file-inside-the-public-folder-in-rails)